# PHP reorder indexes nested array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've this array, that i want to reoder indexes of "Mer" elements.

```
Array

    (
        [Tennis 1] => Array
            (
                [IntervalTime] => Array
                    (
                        [Mer] => Array
                            (
                                [3] => 09:00
                                [4] => 10:00
                                [5] => 11:00
                                [6] => 12:00
                                [7] => 13:00
                                [8] => 14:00
                                [9] => 15:00
                                [10] => 16:00
                                [11] => 17:00
                                [12] => 18:00
                            )

                    )

            )

        [Padel 1] => Array
            (
                [IntervalTime] => Array
                    (
                        [Mer] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 05:00
                                [1] => 06:00
                                [2] => 07:00
                                [3] => 08:00
                                [4] => 09:00
                                [5] => 10:00
                                [6] => 11:00
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

    Array
    (
        [Tennis 1] => Array
            (
                [IntervalTime] => Array
                    (
                        [Mer] => Array
                            (
                                [3] => 09:00
                                [4] => 10:00
                                [5] => 11:00
                                [6] => 12:00
                                [7] => 13:00
                                [8] => 14:00
                                [9] => 15:00
                                [10] => 16:00
                                [11] => 17:00
                                [12] => 18:00
                            )

                    )

            )

        [Padel 1] => Array
            (
                [IntervalTime] => Array
                    (
                        [Mer] => Array
                            (
                                [4] => 09:00
                                [5] => 10:00
                                [6] => 11:00
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

This array is back from

```
unset($DisponibilitaRoom[$room]["IntervalTime"][$Giorni[$DayOfWeekGiornoScelto]][$index]);
```

so i need to reorder this: $DisponibilitaRoom[$room]["IntervalTime"][$Giorni[$DayOfWeekGiornoScelto]],
 but something was wrong in my concept.
I've tried array_values() for this multidimensional array but that was not good.

Any idea is apprectiated.

Comment: `$DisponibilitaRoom[$room]["IntervalTime"][$Giorni[$DayOfWeekGiornoScelto]] = array_values($DisponibilitaRoom[$room]["IntervalTime"][$Giorni[$DayOfWeekGiornoScelto]]);`?

Comment: @Nick, thanks for second time. Please post as solution. It work like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in wanting to use `array_values` to reorder indexes. Based on your array structure, this should work:

```
$DisponibilitaRoom[$room]["IntervalTime"][$Giorni[$DayOfWeekGiornoScelto]] = array_values($DisponibilitaRoom[$room]["IntervalTime"][$Giorni[$DayOfWeekGiornoScelto]]);
```